# Accessing C++ compiled executable binary from Web UI

Tags: c++, node.js, user-interface

If my last question was unclear I will be more descriptive and clear this time:

I wrote a Collector code in C++ and compiled it as an executable binary.
This collector collects data from various servers and write those data into files.

The speed at which data flow to my collector code is at the rate of 10 Gbps and with this speed only the data is written to files.

Now I have been asked to start this binary from Web UI. Which means with a click on Web UI my binary should start running. And its continuously running till life time, until manually its process is killed from the command line.

I am no UI developer so please someone can suggest me how to achieve this.

I have heard about Node.js, but with node js I cannot run my binary.

There is high I/O involved as data is flowing at 10 Gbps so I cannot risk any slowness in here.

Comment: You do not have any web service handling the client request either?

Comment: the server must provide a api function to start the process and do nothing, if the process is started (if i understand you correct) so it will not start another instance and waste resources.

Comment: By starting from WebUI you mean starting locally or on some web server?

Comment: Starting from Web UI I mean it should start as if I am running it locally like ./collector

I just want the Web UI to do that and then have no connection with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running an executable on server side with [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) is as easy as calling [`child_process.spawn()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

You might want to push the contents of the files that your collector generates to clients,

That can be achieved by using [`fs.watch`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) and [**Readable Stream**](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable)s to read the files. And you can use [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/) to broadcast the data to clients.

---

**Update** Here is a simple implementation using [express.js](/questions/tagged/express.js).

```
/**
 * app.js
 * make sure to install express (npm install express)
 * and place the collector executable beside this file
 * or set collectorPath to the correct path.
 * run the app and open 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/start' in your browser.
 */

var child_process = require('child_process');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var collector = null;

app.get('/start', function (req, res) {
  if (collector !== null) {
    res.end('Collector is already running.');
    return;
  }

  var collectorPath = path.join(__dirname, './collector');
  collector = child_process.spawn(collectorPath, [], {
    stdio: 'ignore'
  });

  collector.on('exit', function (signal, code) {
    console.log('Collector exited with signal: %s and code: %d', signal, code);
    collector = null;
  });

  res.end('Done.');
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

Comment: Fardjad -- I just want it to run as if I am running it from the command line like - ./collector

Can I do something like that with Node.js

I don't want node to hold it or there is any blocking

As I have referred the speed is also of a great importance to me, as I am dealing with a speed of 10 Gbps

Comment: Thanks fardjad. I will try with this.

Comment: Fardjad -- will this keep a child process of node alive till the time the binary is running? what will be the scope of this process? what will happen when I will kill the binary process manually from the command line?

Comment: @rakeshsinha collector will be a child process of your node app and will keep running until the collector exits or the node process exits. You can respawn the child process on exit if you want. You can also run your node application as a daemon with **upstart** or **forever** and keep it alive.